# AS or ALIAS is NOT a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.dataframereader

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading now **"SPARK THE DEFINITIVE GUIDE"**; it is a book to learn spark.

And I've been trying to execute some commands and code, but when I tried to execute an command using `AS` I got a message of error saying that

> AS is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.dataframereader ...

I don't know if I have to import an alias function or something like that or I'm missing something.

```
[val flights = flightsDF.as[Flight]]
[result ==> <console>:27: error: value as is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
       val flights = flightsDF.as[Flight]]
```

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rki3E.png)

Thank you, and good luck

Comment: what is `[Flight]`? Is it the case class then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you confused a `DataFrameReader`, an object that read and returns a DataFrame, with a `DataFrame` itself. Use the `load` method on the reader so you have a DataFrame instance. Then you can use `alias` or other DataFrame method on that instance.

The structure of how the DataFrameReader works:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(file)
                 ^    ^             ^                        ^
                 |    |             |                        the actual load action that returns a DataFrame
                 |    |             set extra options on the reader specific to the format
                 |   defines the format type to read
                 creates a DataFrameReader instance
```

Without the `load` method, a file is not loaded and  a `DataFrameReader` is returned. You can see that in your error message.